# matching on nested elastic search documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a nested field in elastic search with the following format,

```
cast = Nested(
    properties={
        'id': Integer(),
        'name': String()
        'type': String()
})
```

I want to construct an ES query that match on the name and return the specific inner document that matched with type, id and other information, (not just the full ES document). Are there any ES available options to retrieve the nested document separately or together with the full ES document.

I considered using the highlight feature of elastic search but highlights only returns the name which matched not the id and type in the document.
Is there a way to achieve this using highlights.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

Comment: this does not return the specific inner document I am looking for, this returns the whole ES document, else I am missing some thing.

Comment: Try to specify fields or look to parent/child